# Spring boot Apache Camel with IBM MQ (back end system is IBM Mainframe) integration example

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, apache-camel

Actually, the Upstream system makes a post request to spring boot rest API, and then this rest controller method receives post request from the upstream system and uses camel route to put the message into IBM MQ (back end system is IBM Mainframe). This is the technical flow but I am not sure how to integrate spring boot camel and then IBM MQ(back end system is IBM Mainframe)integration.

Could you please help some sample code to achieve this

Answer (score 0):

Is [Spring Boot MQ](https://github.com/grovedc/CamelSpringJMS/blob/master/boot-mq-bridge/src/main/resources/spring/camel-context.xml) helpful?  Have a good look at the `pom.xml` file.  Some of the comments are boilerplate and not really useful - apologies for not having cleaned up the example.

Comment: thanks for providing the example but it is in xml configuration, is it possible to provide in java code based example?